# using time out in mootools

Tags: javascript, timeout, mootools

I try to execute some functions with time out, this is code from class:

```
while($$('.visos_prekes ul li.simple').length > 0){
    setTimeout(this.destroyByOne(), 5000);
}

destroyByOne: function(){
    $$('.visos_prekes ul li.simple').each(function(e, key){
        e.destroy();
        if(key > 16){
            return true;
        }
    });
},
```

but this function executes without time out. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `setTimeout(this.destroyByOne(), 5000);` should be:

```
setTimeout(this.destroyByOne, 5000);
```

Because you need to pass it the *function handler* aka variable.....and **not** the result of the function invocation (`this.destroyByOne()`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax of the `setTimeout` function:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

In which `func` is the function (name of the function) you want to execute after delay milliseconds while
`code` in the alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to execute after delay milliseconds!

You can use setTimeout in either of the following:

```
setTimeout(this.destroyByOne, 5000);
setTimeout("this.destroyByOne()", 5000);
```

Comment: You probably do not want to do this `setTimeout("this.destroyByOne()", 5000)` because it will make `setTimeout()` invoke the *evil* **eval()** function. Read: http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/

Comment: Yea sure, just explaining the syntax no pros and cons